# Python to use multiple conditions on 2 data frames and output the outlier

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi I have 2 data frames with multiple columns but just showing relevant columns only:

df1:

| Column A |
| --- |
| CharlesBarkley |
| Michael Jordan |

df2:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| charles barkley | Yes |
| MichaelJordan | No |

I want to achieve the following:

1. I want to first compare df1's Column A to df2's Column A ignoring the space and case-sensitive and making everything lower-case with no space (so it can be michaeljordan).
2. If Column B says No, I want to create a new column and output only the rows that the name matches AND having 'No' for Column B on df2, with the word 'Not Registered' in Python print as follows:

| Column A | Result |
| --- | --- |
| michaeljordan | Not Registered |

How would I be able to achieve this with the Python code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you want to have a new column I filled the other values with the opposite "registered".

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["CharlesBarkley", "Michael Jordan"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["charles barkley", "MichaelJordan"], "B": ["Yes", "No"]})

# Create a mask
same_name = df1["A"].str.replace(" ", "").str.lower() == df2["A"].str.replace(" ", "").str.lower()

df1["result"] = "Registered"
# Apply the mask with another mask to the column "result"
df1.loc[(same_name & (df2["B"] == "No")), "result"] = "Not Registered"
print(df1)
```

This gives you:

```
                A          result
0  CharlesBarkley      Registered
1  Michael Jordan  Not Registered
```

If you want to have only the results that contain "Not Registered":

```
df1[df1["result"] == "Not Registered"]
```